# Is there a more efficient way to write this REGEX to return whole words containing certain letters?

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok so here is some REGEX:

`/\w*a\w*/g` (with global flag)

This is to find any word that has an "a". (example: matches apple, ark and petal in this array P {ent, apple, peter, ark, petal}

Is there anyone who can think of a more efficient way to write this?
Many thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude a from the word characters until you have found it using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) where `\W` matches any non word character.

```
[^\Wa]*a\w*
```

- `[^\Wa]*` Optionally repeat any word chars without a
- `a\w*` Match `a` and optional word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S7VXkr/1)

Comment: This is an efficient solution, thanks. I need to read more about the how each operation scans the texts to be able to understand better how and why, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or not use a regex, this is more readable

```js
const letter = "a",
arr = ["ent", "apple", "peter", "ark", "petal"];
console.log(arr.filter(word=>word.includes(letter)))
```

Comment: Hi, your answer works, however I was looking for a REGEX optimization for a reason (I wanted to reuse this code on on middleware that are not necessarily coded in Javascript). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I use `[^\W]*a[^\W]*`to match all words containing the letter `a`

Comment: That's just negating the negation making it MORE complicated `[^\W]`is the same as `\w` :/